# Preformatted templates in php

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, ms-word

I basically trying to move a manual approach into a web app.

Current way:

1. We have some, nice looking preformatted word templates (.dotx), these are basically proposals which we sent to our customers.
2. We open the appropriate template, fill in some blanks and sent it to customer. that's easy and quick.

Now I have to sort of achieve the same into a web app.. So say I select a template, that loads in and I can fill in the blanks and save it. I should I able to come back and open it in the same state I saved it and I can export it to and PDf so that I can send it to client.

**How can I do this. I am not actually asking for any code here but possible approaches so that I can compare and see which can work for me.**

Answer (score 0):

Find a PHP library for working with word documents, then have a form for the data you input, which then sends a POST to a script that takes that data and puts it into the template, and save the file on the server. Now you've got this file on the server... if you have access to the server itself you can edit and export that just using Word, but if you want that functionality through the web app, you'll need things like pages to view the list of saved files, export saved files, and sending them.

Answer (score 0):

1) You create tables `form` and `form_field` in database;
2) You create new from. It's simple `<form></form>` stuff;
3) Save this form fields to database. Use [`PDO`](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) or [`mysqli_*`](http://www.phphaven.com/article.php?id=65%C2%A0), not `mysql_*`
4) List all forms from database;
5) After selecting existing form, you just load data from database;
6) To save form data to PDF, use PDF class for that, like [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/).

I suggest using this type of db structure, since you can have different fields for different forms:

```
[form]
id (PK) (int) | name (VARCHAR) | description (VARCHAR) | order (int) | active (boolean)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1                F1                   Desc                  1               1
 2                F2                   Desc                  2               1

[form_field]
id (PK) (int) | form_id (FK) (int) | name (varchar) | value (varchar) | descriptive_name (varchar) | required (boolean)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1                  2                 user_name         ano@zet.lt            User Name                   1
  2                  2                 phone              +316546              Phone                       0
```